# how to free memory for structure variable

Tags: c++

```
typdef struct _structname  
{  
    int x;  
    string y;  
} structure_name;

structure_name variable;
```

Now I access `variable.x` and `y`. After using it how can i deallocate or free the memory used by `variable`?

Actually the memory is getting allocated when i am doing **variable.y="sample string"**.So the = operator allocates memory which is causing issue. how can i resolve it now?

Comment: Use the *format code* button above the edit field to format code.

Comment: which issue do you mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Memory needs to be deallocated only when it's dynamically allocated.

Dynamic allocation is done using either `new` or `malloc`, and deallocation is done using `delete` or `free` respectively.

If your program doesn't use `new` or `malloc` anywhere, then you don't need to use `delete` or `malloc` either. Note there will be as many number of `delete` as there are `new`. And same is true of `malloc` and `free` also.

That is, in a program:

- Number of *executed* `new` statements is equal to the number of *executed* `delete`  statements!
- Number of *executed* `malloc` statements is equal to the number of *executed* `free`  statements!

If there are less number of *executed* `delete` or `free`, then your program is Leaking Memory. If there are less number of *executed* `new` or `malloc` then your program will most likely crash!

Comment: Actually the memory is getting allocated when i am doing variable.y="sample string".So the = operator allocates memory which is causing issue. how can i resolve it now?

Comment: @SPB: memory is getting allocated by std::string class, not by yourself. So you don't need to worry about it. As I said, IF you use new, then you've to use delete, otherwise not, at least not in the scenario!

Answer (score 7):

You've allocated the structure on the stack.  The memory it's using will be freed when it goes out of scope.  If you want to have control over when the memory is freed theh you should investigate dynamic memory allocation.

Answer (score 4):

In C++ you don't need to "typedef" your structures.

Use:

```
struct structure_name
{
    int x;
    int y;
};
```

If you create myVar this way:

```
structure_name myVar;
```

You don't need to deallocate it, it will automatically be destroyed and freed when going out of scope.

If you had used pointers (created with the "new" keyword ) you'd need to free them explicitly using the "delete" keyword.

In C++ you will use pointers only in specific cases.

Answer (score 1):

The lifetime of a variable can be controlled by introducing a pair of braces `{` `}`.

```
{
    structure_name variable; // memory for struct allocated on stack
    variable.y = "sample string"; // y allocates storage on heap

    // ...

} // variable goes out of scope here, freeing memory on stack and heap
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to free since you have declared them as values and not pointers and not allocationg memory dynamically.

memory needs to be freed only when you allocate memory dynamically.